# No Overload for '' match delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#

There is error about

```
ParameterizedThreadStart op = new ParameterizedThreadStart(new EventHandler(this.SendResultToClient));
```

No Overload for 'SendResultToClient' match delegeate 'System.EventHandler'

any help

```
 public void Add(double num)
   {
    double result = (num+10);
             //Gets a channel to the client instance that called the current operation.
            callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IAddNumDuplexCallback>();
            //Represents the method that executes on a Thread.
            ParameterizedThreadStart op = new ParameterizedThreadStart(new EventHandler(this.SendResultToClient));
            Thread t = new Thread(op);
             //t.IsBackground = true;
             t.Start(result);
         }

        //The function
        public void SendResultToClient(double result)
        {
          Thread.Sleep(500);
          callback.Result(result);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an EventHandler?

Comment: This is example , about Duplex Contract in WCF4 ,

Comment: Clearly `Thread t = new Thread( () => SendResultToClient(result); }` would aboid the EventHandler taking more args, but the WPF context changes this. You need to make the context clearer in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ParameterizedThreadStart` in the wrong way.

`ParameterizedThreadStart` is a delegate for a method that accepts one argument of type object and returns void.

You need to change your `SendResultToClient` method in:

```
public void SendResultToClient(object data)
{
    double result = (double)data;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    callback.Result(result);
}
```

and start the thread in this way:

```
ParameterizedThreadStart op = SendResultToClient;
Thread t = new Thread(op);
t.Start(result);
```